# bypass ip destination squid tproxy bridge

Tags: centos, iptables, proxy, squid, bridge

I have configured a [squid transparent tproxy](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4). All works fine.

Now I need all the traffic going to an external IP (internet) does not pass through the proxy.

Do I need to modify iptables, ebetables rules or change the configuration of squid?

I found [this tutorial](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/TransparentProxySelectiveBypass), but it doesn't use the tproxy rules.

iptables rules:

```
iptables -F -t mangle
iptables -X -t mangle
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT

iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 3129
```

ebtables rules:

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i eth1 -p ipv4 --ip-proto tcp --ip-dport 80 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i eth0 -p ipv4 --ip-proto tcp --ip-sport 80 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP
```

Looks like I need to insert the bypass rules before the first ebtables rule. Is that correct?

Do these rules works?

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i eth1 -p ipv4 --ip-proto -d IP_dest -j ACCEPT
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i eth0 -p ipv4 --ip-proto -s IP_dest -j ACCEPT
```